# Поведение и повадка - это этимологически родственные слова?

Tags: этимология

Слово ***поведение***, очевидно,  происходит от глагола ***вести***, например: как ты себя ведешь. Это нейтральный стиль, вполне благопристойное семейство.

***Повадки*** животных ― тоже нормальное сочетание. ПОВАДКА, Разг. Привычка к выполнению каких-л. действий; закрепившийся навык, манера поведения. Птичьи повадки.

Да только вот  у глагола ***вадить*** репутация не из лучших. В современном языке можно встретить родственные ему слова: ***привадить, отвадить, повадиться, наваждение,*** все они  с негативным подтекстом.

Сам же глагол ***вадить***  и существительное ***вада*** также означали весьма предосудительные понятия: обман, лесть, ссору, клевету, дурные привычки, основанные на слабостях человеческого рода, да и животных тоже, например: https://dicti.net/?dalw=%E2%E0%E4%E8%F2%FC

Но каково же происхождение глагола ***вадить***, есть ли у него порядочные родственники? Так, Черных считал это слово этимологически неясным и в принципе допускал его индоевропейское родство с глаголом ***вести.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, в далёком прошлом это были всё же родственные слова - от слова вести. Поведение - от вести, повадка - от вадить, вада. Вада родственно важда, от него наваждение.

Этимологический словарь русского языка Семенова говорит:

Древнерусское " наваждение" заимствовано из старославянского языка и означает «обманчивое видение, внушенное злой силой», «дьявольские козни». Слово является производным от глагола навадити («наговаривать», «внушать»).

Факты, касающиеся происхождения данного слова, являются спорными, исследователи сходятся лишь в одном – в основе данной лексической единицы лежит индоевропейский корень со значением «водить».

Родственными являются:

Украинское – навождення.

Чешское – vaditi (мешать).

Литовское – vadinti (именовать, звать).

Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н.( 1935-1940) утверждает:

НАВОЖДЕНИЕ (наваждение устар.), навождения, ср. В поверьях - призрак, обманчивое видение, внушенноезлой силой с целью соблазна.
|| Непонятное, поразительное явление, трудно объяснимый случай (разг. шутл.).

Так что наваждение - это и есть навождение. У М.Горького есть роман "Навождение". Навождение - представитель тёмных сил "навёл" морок, порчу.

В. Даль приводит много значений слова вадить:

ВА́ДИТЬ кого, чем; ва́живать - манить, привлекать, прикармливать, приваживать; || что на кого, стар., а иногда и ныне: клеветать на кого, наговаривать. || Новг. манить, проводить, обманывать. Он вадит день за́ день; вадит посулами. || Пенз. играя в поты́чки, чушки,водить кон? конаться? (кажется, это будет води́ть, а не ва́дить). Кий на кий вадит, а хлеб на хлеб не вадит, палка на драку вызывает, а хлеб-соль забывается. 
Ва́диться вологодск. готовиться к чему, собираться, приучаться, навыка́ть. Он севого́ды вадится сплавать к городу, готовится плыть в Архангельск. Взвадить на кого, наклеветать. Козел ввадился в огород; вы́вадить, отва́дить кого, отучить. Не доваживай малого до беды, не балуй его. Завадил, привадил тетеревей и накрыл шатром, сетью. Извадится овца, не хуже козы. Навадили кошку (избаловали), не скоро отвадишь. Повадился воробей в конопельку. Повадку не перевадишь. Приваживать рыбу блевкою. Провадил меня, проманил обещаниями, провел. Свадили у меня кучера, сманили.

Ва́дкий, ва́дный, соблазнительный, пова́дчивый. Это кус ва́дкий. || Вадкий,жидкий, см.вадья. Накажи, чтоб не больно ва́дно было баловаться, неповадно. Ва́день м. смол. овод, слепень, бут, паут; || докучала, надоедала. Ва́да ж. пск. повадка, поблажка, поноровка. Не дай вады ему. || Зап. повадка, попущение самому себе, дурной навык, порок. Одна в ём вада,  трохи картавый. || Зап. соблазн, ссора, сплетни и брань. С им без вады не будешь.

В играх в отдельных областях водить и вадить близки по значению:-Чур, я вожу!(встаёт в круг и выкрикивает, что положено по условиям игры)- Я его завадил -
 победил (назначил следующим ведущим)

Получается, вадить - диалектное слово от древнерусского вада, а важда - старославянское, а суть одна - крик, наговор, внушение, наведение морока. Навести - от вести. Всё равно всё возвращается к "вести".

Answer (score 3):

У Фасмера высказана гипотеза, что "недобрые" значения глагола "**вадить**" могли локально трансформироваться в значения "*приманивать, приучать*" с родственными существительными (**вада** - повадка, привычка) в ряде славянских языков и даже в греческом ("обычай"):
http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-1556.htm

Нежелательный оттенок привычного поведения просматривается и в современных глаголах "**повадиться**" (взять в привычку делать что-то нехорошее) и "**отвадить**" (отучить от обыкновения делать что-то нежелательное). Так или иначе, корень этих слов Даль и Фасмер не связывают по происхождению с корнем слова "поведение" - вероятно, эти слова появились *независимыми* путями.

Comment: Можно предположить, что "вадить" родилось из охотничьего арго. Одних животных нужно было приваживать, Для добычи и одомашнивания. Других - отваживать, чтобы, скажем, сберечь посевы и заготовки. Поэтому и значение (знак) было разным. Но всё это, а тем более, привязка к "поведению", это чистая эмпирика. В этом слове даже и сейчас чувствуется другой изначальный смысл.

Comment: Черных указывает на существование др.-инд. варианта vadati - говорить, сообщать. В целом семантика слова связана с речевым или чувственным воздействием на объект с целью формирования у него поведенческих уставок, взглядов, привычек. Поэтому так близки эти значения - водить/вести (непосредственно) и вадить (также вести, но способом непрямого действия). И и.-е. корни у слов очень похожи: ved(h) - вести,  ved - вадить.

Answer (score 1):

Осторожно выскажу предположение, что "Вад" в древности и означало - "инстинкт".

"Вед" - это и в родственных языках имеет смысловое значение - "думать". То есть - вести связный рассказ. Не "мыслить", а именно - "рассказывать".

А может быть "вед" и "вад" были когда-то словами-антагонистами?

Comment: Эти слова больше на родственные похожи: иметь знания и воздействовать с их помощью на окружающих.

Comment: "Вад", скорее воздействует на самоё себя. Непреодолимо воздействует. Если копнуть очень глубоко, то Ваджра (санскр.) имеет одно из значений - "непреодолимое воздействие". Если сопоставить это значение с "приманкой", то та тоже непреодолимо воздействует на зверя. Манок или же отпугивающие запахи и звуки.

Answer (score 0):

Интересно, что в слове "поведение" корень "вед" содержит в себе целый куст значений, составляющих синкретическое целое.
Это, во-первых, "вести себя каким-то образом" или "вести кого-либо за собой". Во-вторых, "ведать (знать), куда вести". В-третьих, "ведать что-либо" — это когда-либо в прошлом увидеть это. В-четвёртых, идти куда-то, чтобы что-то увидеть, — это идти на разведку. В-пятых, вести кого-либо за собой для того, чтобы в конечном итоге не вывести их на цель, а погубить, как поступил Сусанин с поляками, — введение кого-либо в заблуждение, вождение за нос. В-шестых, тот, кто ведёт за собой, — вождь. Обычно вождь ведает, куда он ведёт своё войско (народ), или высылает вперёд кого-либо на разведку.
Вид — вед — вод — вад. Видеть — ведать — водить — привадить — отвадить — повадки. Повадка — устоявшаяся форма поведения, возникшая вследствие научения (поисково-ориентировочной активности). Научение, естественно, сохраняется в привычках и навыках.